# VK API: загрузка фото на стену возвращает пустое photo

Tags: java, curl, http, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь [прикрепить фото к посту](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F), но upload-сервер возвращает

> {"server":619324,"photo":"[]","hash":"235eb464133565b70d01ee4b174b2697"}

## Шаги

1. Получаю `uload_url` через [photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id)](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getWallUploadServer)
2. Делаю **POST**-запрос на uload_url, где параметр формы **photo** содержит jpg-файл.

## Дамп POST-запроса

Это дамп запроса, которые я получаю с Java-версии

```
POST /upload.php?act=do_add&mid=231464696&aid=-14&gid=74806856&hash=2b2c4e818d938b4202e736bccb6de22e&rhash=d22a5b85bf5bd8298f193b4318c8d54d&swfupload=1&api=1&wallphoto=1  HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 233477
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=0g6_BF339gILdnLw48ZE7ZTnTHz-pcIMiQG7Y
Host: cs619324.vk.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: remixlang=0
Cookie2: $Version=1

--0g6_BF339gILdnLw48ZE7ZTnTHz-pcIMiQG7Y
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="photo.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(Бинарное содержимое файла)
...
```

## Как я делаю запрос через curl

```
$ curl -F photo=@photo.jpg $uload_url
```

## Как я делаю запрос на Java

Используется `Apache HTTP-client 4`. Результат аналогичен `curl`.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(server.toURI());
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .setLaxMode()
        .addBinaryBody(fileName, image, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), fileName + ".jpeg")
        .build();
post.setEntity(entity);
getNewHttpClient().execute(post);

HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(null, null);
    SSLSocketFactory sf = new EmptySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
    sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 3 * 60 * 1000);

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

    ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

    return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
}
```

---

- Аналогичные действия для заливки фото в альбом (photos.getUploadServer) работают корректно.
- Находил [похожие сообщения об ошибках](https://vk.com/topic-1_22034478?post=72433), но не помогло.

Answer (score 2):

Используй Fiddler и проксируй все запросы через него - это поможет быстрее понять в чём ошибка.
Для начала попробуй в браузере на старнице метода выполнить загрузку файла и в Fiddler посмотреть как формируется запрос, затем проверь как работает твой код. Ошибка будет видна практически сразу.

В моём случае PHP не отправляло содержимое файла.